# Ajax code not working properly

Tags: php, ajax

(sorry for my english).

What I want to do is to basic database insert .Actually inserting part works fine the problem is index.php redirects process.php after inserting.But It should stay at  the same page and the clear all the fields  What am I doing wrong.

this is index.php file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="process.php" id="myForm" method="post">
    UserName <input type="text" name="uname"><br>
    Pass <input type="text" name="pass"><br>
    FirstName <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
    LastName <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <button id="submit" value="register"></button>


</form>
<div id="ack">Ack</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="site.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the site.js

```
$("#submit").click( function() {

    $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
        $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
        function(info) {

            $("#ack").empty();
            $("#ack").html(info);
            clear();
        });

    $("#myForm").submit( function() {
        return false;
    });
});

function clear() {

    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
        $(this).val("");
    });

}
```

And this is for inserting

```
<?php
require("config.php");
$uname =$_POST["uname"];
$pass = $_POST["pass"];
$fname = $_POST["fname"];
$lname = $_POST["lname"];

$insert=$db->prepare("insert into users (uname,pass,fname,lname) values(?,?,?,?)");
$insert->bind_param("ssss",$uname,$pass,$fname,$lname);
if($insert->execute()){
    echo "ok";
}
else
{$db->error;}

?>
```

Comment: You don't have a submit to capture, but you need to prevent the default action of the click.

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure you ***[don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: thank you for your help and tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try it like this;

```
$("#myForm").submit( function() {
    return false;
    });

$("#submit").click( function() {

$.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"),
    $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info) {

        $("#ack").empty();
        $("#ack").html(info);
        clear();
    });
});

function clear() {

    $("#myForm :input").each( function() {
        $(this).val("");
    });
}
```

Comment: Not at all. Greetings from Turkey :)